# Raspberry pi zero w clone problems

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, raspbian-lite

I am using raspberry to develop kiosk lcd screen. When i ended developing i cloned sd card and copy it to other rpi’s but  others aren’t working same as first one. There are problems like: chromium won’t start in kiosk, wifi won’t connect, rtc clock not detected etc.

Is there any folder that i need to renew/clear when i am cloning to new rpi? What can i do?

Only way i  am able to do it is to install raspberian lite from begining, but it is a long procedure.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe *how* you are cloning the SD cards.  Also say whether you've tested the original SD card in one of the Pis where the clone fails.

Comment: @BobBrown for cloning SD cards i am using win32diskimage software. If i  put cloned sd card into rpi that was developed on it works. But if i put sd card clone in any other rpi it doesnt work. Is it possible that maybe image contains somekind of processor id or something like it, that is not compatible with new processor id ...?

Comment: "maybe image contains somekind of processor id" - not unless you put one in there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about your image but as far as I know there is no central point to fix and everything is running. You have to look at every program why it does not work and look for a setup it can start from a cloned image. With some luck there is only one setting that effects most programs, for example the network connection. Chromium and wifi need that. Have a look at `journalctl -b -e`. Maybe you will see what's going wrong and why the operating system does not find the real time clock.